# Django (Models): how to get instance from foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models, sqlite

i'm new to django and sqlite. Is that possible i can get the instance.name value from its foreign key that is related to modeldb? I need to save my pdf file under the same directory as the modeldb class. From the above experiment, im got nothing with modelDB.instance / modelDB.instance.name.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: noted. will not do this next time... cause the code running on VM so its hard to copy over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move that `upload` function outside the class.

instance refer as the your class instance. So you can do like this

```
instance.modelDB.name

citatiions = models.FileField(...., upload_to=upload) #pass your function name here
```

check this answer[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43603648/django-how-to-rename-images-using-a-new-auto-numbering-per-foreign-key/43604136#43604136)

Comment: dosent seems working... i though (self) will just call Citations class only? which it return "documents/pdf/filename"

Comment: opps... thats my own problem, i forget to update the parameter at upload_to. your code is working. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You could do,

```
def upload(instance, file_name):
    return "documents/" + instance.ModelDB.name + "/pdf/" + filename
```

Comment: thanks Fazil, your code is working... I just forgot to update my parameter on models.filefield. thanks for you help.